# Using Cordova Config Tags to add Intent Filter in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

**Ionic 2 / Cordova 7.0.1**

Trying to insert intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml using config tags. I was reading Cordova documentation and I am confused about the config tags usage. Can tags be used directly in Config.xml or only in plugins?

Here's my Config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <activity android:label="webIntentFilter" android:name="com.domain.myapp">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="www.android.com" android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="www.android.com" android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Don't know what I'm missing but nothing happens. I've tried using *cordova custom config plugin* but that erases my Launcher and inserts the intent filter twice.

Comment: are those configs you mentioned in config.xml getting in AndroidManifest.xml after android platform build?

Comment: Curious to know if you've resolved this... I'm running into the same issue.